# control Gridview Based on Selection of more than one Drop down List

Tags: c#, .net, database

I created a data base named as Ztv.mdf , table as tabl1 with [Name], [fullname], [Id],[dept]& also
created a drop down list1 for dept.when the dept values selected by user from dropdown list1 the gridview shows the output.it works fine.But i want 1 more dropdown list for Name.my aim is that when user select values from both dropdownlist1 & dropdown list2 it contol the grid view.how can i do it?

my code for 1 dropdown list & grid view is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchCriteria" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="depat" DataValueField="Id" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ztvConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [depat] FROM [Table1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" style="margin-left: 155px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="fullname" HeaderText="fullname" 
                SortExpression="fullname" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ztvConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [fullname], [Id] FROM [Table1] WHERE ([Id] = @Id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSearchCriteria" Name="Id" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can create a cascade filters, such a when the user select the dept  in the first dropdown list in the second dropdown list display the name of the user whom belong to the first drop down list and filter the gridview based on the value selected in the second dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stored procedure to bind data to grid view using more than one drop down list selection.Pass dropdown selected values to stored procedure as a argument and get result.
I have implemented this like.

```
 public void BindGridList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (CompMSEntities1 CompObj = new CompMSEntities1())
            {
                DateTime Start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
                DateTime End = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
                Int32 Department = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDept.SelectedValue);
                Int32 Category = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
                Int32 Priority = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPriority.SelectedValue);
                Int32 Status = Convert.ToInt32(ddlStatus.SelectedValue);
                GridViewComplaintReport.DataSource = CompObj.SP_ManageComplaint_Summary(Start, End, Department, Category, Priority, Status);
                SP_ManageComplaint_Summary_Result obj = new SP_ManageComplaint_Summary_Result();
                GridViewComplaintReport.DataBind();
                GridViewComplaintReport.Visible = true;
                ExportTable.Visible = true;
                TableGrid.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblException.Text = "Problem in data retrive from database .";
            lblException.Visible = true;
            ErrorHandler.WriteError(ex.ToString());
        }
```

> code for stored procedure-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  dbo.SP_ManageComplaint_Summary


  @StartDate datetime,
  @EndDate datetime,
  @DepartmentID INT,
  @CategoryID INT,
  @PriorityID INT ,    

  @StatusID INT

AS
BEGIN

  SELECT d1.DepartmentName,c1.CategoryName,s1.StatusType,
  p1.PriorityType,c.Title, c.[Description], c.Created,c.DueDate,
  u1.Email, u1.UserID, c.QMRClosedDate

  FROM  Complaint   c   
  Inner  JOIN Department  d1 ON c.DepartmentID = d1.DepartmentID
  Inner JOIN Category  c1  ON c.CategoryID = c1.CategoryID
  Inner JOIN Priority  p1  on c.PriorityID = p1.PriorityID
  Inner JOIN UserInfo   u1 on c.UserID = u1.UserID   
  Inner JOIN [Status]  s1 on c.StatusID = s1.StatusID   


  WHERE 
 c.Created  BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate+1   AND


     d1.DepartmentID = Case when @DepartmentID = -1 then d1.DepartmentID else @DepartmentID end AND        
     c1.CategoryID = Case when @CategoryID = -1 then  c1.CategoryID else @CategoryID end AND
     p1.PriorityID = Case when @PriorityID = -1 then p1.PriorityID  else @PriorityID end AND
     s1.StatusID =Case When @StatusID = -1 then s1.StatusID else @StatusID end
```